# Security error with matching origins in android chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am opening popup and call `window.opener.someFunc();` from it.

In some android devices I have such error:

> SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xDomain" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "https://xDomain". Protocols, domains,
>   and ports must match.

As you can see origins match but anyway I get this error. What is wrong?